# Use the Forward Difference method to approximate the solution to the following PDE?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Use the Forward Difference method to approximate the solution to the following PDE:

$$
u^3\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}-x^2u\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}=2x^8t^7+6x^6t^5+4x^4t^3 
$$
for $0\le x\le1$

U(0,t)= 1

U(1,t) = $t^2+1$

U(x,0)= 1 for $0\le x\le1$

Find u at t=1. Use h=0.1 and k=.0002

If appropriate:

- Find matrix A and vector B for Au=B
- Find the Jacobian J and the vector F for Newton's method
  Do not solve. Show all of the derivatives.

We did an example like this one in class but what is really throwing me off about this problem is that we don't have a range for 't' and the two spatial derivatives are equal to a function. The one we solved in class was equal to 0. Also, how do I know which method to use? I know that we use newton's method for non linear ODE's and the other method for linear ODE's. However, I don't know if this will work for PDE's.

I was just hoping someone will walk me through this problem so that I can finish the two I have for homework and understand them better for my final.

Thank you!

Comment: As you're asked about solution at $t=1$ you can assume that $t$ range is $0 \leq t \leq 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Forward difference**. Assuming "forward difference" is related to the time derivative only. Let $x_j = jh$ be the $j$-th spatial point of the grid and the $t_n = kn$ be the $n$-th time layer. Let $u^n_j$ be the $u(t_n, x_j)$. As you're asked for a forward difference method you should approximate time derivative $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ using
$$
\frac{u^{n+1}_j - u^n_j}{k}
$$
and take everything else from the $n$-th time layer. That is applied to right hand side, every coefficient before derivatives and the $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$ derivative. To deal with the second derivative let's approximate it using the conventional formula
$$
\frac{u^n_{j-1} - 2u^n_j + u^n_{j+1}}{h^2}.
$$
Collecting it alltogether we obtain
$$
(u^n_j)^3 \frac{u^{n+1}_j - u^n_j}{k} - (x_j)^2 u^n_j
\frac{u^n_{j-1} - 2u^n_j + u^n_{j+1}}{h^2} = 2(x_j)^8(t_n)^7 + 6 (x_j)^6 (t_n)^5 + 4(x_j)^4 (t_n)^3.
$$
This difference equation holds for every $j = 1, \dots, M-1$, i.e. everythere except the borders. Here $j=M$ is index of the right border $x_M = 1$. To compute $u^{n+1}_0$ and $u^{n+1}_M$ you can use the boundary conditions
$$
u^{n+1}_0 = 1, \qquad u^{n+1}_M = (t_{n+1})^2 + 1.
$$
To start with you have the initial conditions
$$
u^0_j = 1.
$$
This in an *explicit* sheme, since it can be easily solved for $u^{n+1}_j$ for every $j = 0, \dots, M$ provided that you already know $u^n_j$. No linear or nonlinear systems need to be solved.

**Backward difference**. Applying same technique, but using 
$$
\frac{u^{n}_j-u^{n-1}_j}{k}
$$
approximation for $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ results in more complicated scheme
$$
(u^n_j)^3 \frac{u^n_j - u^{n-1}_j}{k} - (x_j)^2 u^n_j
\frac{u^n_{j-1} - 2u^n_j + u^n_{j+1}}{h^2} = \qquad\qquad\qquad\\\qquad\qquad\qquad = 2(x_j)^8(t_n)^7 + 6 (x_j)^6 (t_n)^5 + 4(x_j)^4 (t_n)^3, \quad j = 1,\dots,M-1,\, n > 0\\
u_0^n = 1,\qquad u^n_M = (t_n)^2 + 1,\qquad u^0_j = 1.
$$
The complication comes from the fact that you can not easily solve the equations for $u^n_j$ if you know $u^{n-1}_j$. Now it's become a system of nonlinear equations for $u^n_j$.
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{u}) &= 0, \text{where}\\\\
F_0(u_0^n, u_1^n, \dots, u^n_M) &= u^n_0 - 1\\
F_j(u_0^n, u_1^n, \dots, u^n_M) &= (u^n_j)^3 \frac{u^n_j - u^{n-1}_j}{k} - (x_j)^2 u^n_j
\frac{u^n_{j-1} - 2u^n_j + u^n_{j+1}}{h^2} - \\& - 2(x_j)^8(t_n)^7 - 6 (x_j)^6 (t_n)^5 - 4(x_j)^4 (t_n)^3\\
F_M(u_0^n, u_1^n, \dots, u^n_M) &= u^n_M - 1 - (t_{n})^2.
\end{aligned}
$$
Note that $u^{n-1}_j$ term in $F_j(\cdot)$ is already known. This system can be numerically solved using Newton's method.

Comment: Do you solve it with newtons method because you are using backward difference?

Comment: Exactly. Since the scheme is no more explicit like in forward difference case